# Oracle TO_CHAR function for timestamp works when manually running query, but when retrieved in Java, gives null value

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am working on a java web application that retrieves data from an Oracle db. I am trying to get a timestamp out of the database and then store it in a model class as a string.

When manually running the query with Oracle SQL Developer, such as the following, the results display normally:

```
SELECT
TO_CHAR(t.last_modified_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF5') as last_modified_timestamp 
FROM table t
WHERE t.id = 2
```

Results are "2017-02-06 14:03:54.33000".

However, when getting the results programmatically, using a prepared statement, the result for the last_modified_timestamp column is null. All the other columns populate properly. Example:

```
sql = "SELECT
TO_CHAR(t.last_modified_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF5') as last_modified_timestamp,
to_char(t.created_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as created_date
FROM table t
WHERE t.id = ?";

PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
ps.setLong(1, orderId);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

if(rs.next()) {
    log.debug(rs.getString("created_date"));
    log.debug(rs.getString("last_modified_timestamp"));
}
```

The created_date column has result "02/06/2017", but last_modified_timestamp just shows null.

Comment: what happens if you rename the alias to `last_modified_timestamp_char` and then use `rs.getString("last_modified_timestamp_char")`?

Comment: Tried that, still had same issue.

Comment: try setting the `orderId` to 2

Comment: Often this is a sign of uncommitted transactions. Judging by the timestamp, the row had just been inserted. You can see it from the same session you inserted it from, but your Java code (running in its own session) can't until you `COMMIT`.

Comment: @mathguy: Aha! This was it. I am still not very familiar with SQL Developer so I made the changes but forgot to hit the little 'commit' icon. The changes appeared in the table but were not in fact written to the database.

Comment: @haystack: I just thought that if your orderId is not 2 then you select a row where `t.last_modified_timestamp` is null in the table. The record for the t.id=2 contains the correct value, as you have tested it already

Comment: @haystack - I've done that many times, and I don't even code in Java! Just changing a table in SQL Developer and then running something against it in an (obviously different) SQL\*Plus session, or vice versa.